# Unable to post full size image to timeline using Python

Tags: python-3.x, getstream-io

I have a React-Native app that if I use the  component and post an image to the timeline it is a full screen image. However... I am wanting to post an image server side using Python and I am unable to get the code right for posting an image that is full screen.

I have found the examples for posting images to be quite limited, and I have tried a few different combinations which I have pasted below.

```py
user_feed = client.feed('timeline', user_id)
            user_feed.add_activity({'actor': client.users.create_reference(user_id),
                                    "verb": "post",
                                    "object": 'my message to see if this thing actually works',
                                    "attachments": {
                                        "og": {
                                            "title": "Crozzon di Brenta photo by Lorenzo Spoleti",
                                            "description": "Download this photo in Italy by Lorenzo Spoleti",
                                            "url": "https://unsplash.com/photos/yxKHOTkAins",
                                            "images": [
                                                {
                                                    "image": public_image_url
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }})
```

The code above posts the image as a thumbnail with a description. If I remove the title and description, the image still posts as a small thumbnail - is there a way to get rid of the box and make it look like image 2 (full screen)? [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvAil.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgJ34.png)

Comment: Fixed it... found this page: https://getstream.github.io/react-native-activity-feed/#!/UI%20Components

Answer (score 0):

As per https://getstream.github.io/react-native-activity-feed/#!/UI%20Components

```py
const activity = {
  actor: {
    data: {
      name: 'Nora Ferguson',
      profileImage: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/72.jpg',
    },
  },
  verb: 'post',
  object: 'Just came back from this hike! #Hiking #Madeira',
  image:
    'https://handluggageonly.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/IMG_0777.jpg',
  time: new Date(),
};
```